# How to populate a FlatList's header with data from the network?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` that displays a user's comments and I want to also populate the header with the user's profile (which is a different network call from the one fetching the comments).

Here's how `render()` looks like:

```
render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data = {this.state.comments}
        renderItem = {this.renderComment}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        keyExtractor={(comment, index) => comment.id}
      />
    )
  }
```

and then `renderHeader` looks like:

```
  renderHeader() {
     return (
      <ProfileView user={this.state.profile} />
    )
  }
```

I use `fetch` in `componentWillMount` and then `setState` in order to get the data (this part works fine).
Now the error I get on the simulator is

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.profile')

but when I remove the `renderHeader` method, comments are fetched properly.

Since I'm very new to RN, can you help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You should read https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb for how to properly use `this`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like simply an issue with accessing context. When you run the `renderHeader` method called by the `FlatList` it doesn't know what `this` relates to.

So, you can simply set `this.renderHeader = this.renderHeader.bind(this)` in your `constructor()` method.

Alternatively, you should also be able to use an arrow function to call it, as this automatically refers to the correct `this` context.

```
ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
```

Comment: Second snippet won't work, FlatList isn't probably modifying the context, it is just not set at all as you said with the constructor snippet

Comment: Thanks for your answer - being new to JavaScript it pointed me to the right direction (and I found [this article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) very helpful).